# How to save multiple files under in 1 django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, crud, django-file-upload

I'm fairly new to Django. I have a model copy (exam copy of a student), the model copy will contain a student test or exam copy and a mark, usually, i would use a FileField and save the copy to the object, but my problem is that a copy could contain many files (page 1, 2, 3 etc)

I was thinking about using a CharField instead that contains the path to a folder that contains the files for that copy, but I don't have a very good idea on how to do that

and if you have a better way I would for you to share.

here is my model

```
class VersionCopie(models.Model):
    id_version = models.CharField(db_column='id_Version', primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    numero_version = models.IntegerField(db_column='numero_Version', blank=True, null=True)
    note_copie = models.FloatField(db_column='note_Copie', blank=True, null=True)
    emplacement_copie = models.CharField(db_column='emplacement_Copie', max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True)
    id_copie = models.ForeignKey('Copie', models.CASCADE, db_column='id_Copie', blank=True, null=True)
```

i just need to know what kind of path i would save to "emplacement_copie"

Comment: May you better explain what do you mean my Copy, and a file containing many pages? Why not just upload the file to a FileField?

Comment: like an exam copy, i can't use a FileField because 1 exam copy could have many files (many pages)

Comment: Side node: there's no need to define primary key in Django. You're already provided with an integer field named `pk` and you shouldn't override it without reason.

Comment: I do have a reason, I gave 27 models in total so I'm giving each model a key to avoid confusion, for example, students would be etud1 etud2 etud3 .. etc and copies would be copy1 copy2 copy3 ... etc

Comment: Keys from different models don't interfere with each other. They just count from 1 to N independently. You're just introducing confusion and it might byte you in the future

Comment: @MaciejDziuban i'm not talking about confusion from a Django point of view, i'm referring to the sysadmin that will be using this app and filling the data...... what would be the issues generated by what i'm doing ?

Comment: You might want to delete this field one day and you won't be able to do it easily. If you want to have unique fields, just use unique=True. Also (this is my speculation), it might slow down querying, because integers are faster to compare than strings. Give this post a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055784/what-is-the-best-approach-to-change-primary-keys-in-an-existing-django-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think this is classical one-to-many relation. You have probably already implemented something like that by doing `id_copie = models.ForeignKey(...)`

You should create separate model, representing just one file and containing reference to your VersionCopie. You can still access all files from VersionCopy model, reference is created implictly (see this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)).

Example code:

```
class VersionCopyFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField( <your arguments> )
    version_copy = models.ForeignKey(VersionCopy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: that a good idea, but i was hoping for a way to contain it to just that one model

Comment: Django provides you with a Python wrapper for relational database and it transforms your code to SQL code (at least by default). And this is how it's done in SQL, you can't have arrays