# Django is generating invalid SQL for Postgres

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I'm a noob django user, and I'm having some trouble with the Model.objects.all method.
I've got a user model:
(I know keeping passwords in plaintext is bad practice, but this is just supposed to be a toy example)

```
class UsersModel(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH, primary_key=True)
    count = models.IntegerField()
```

And I've got a test method that's supposed to drop all the entries in the user table:

```
def function(self):
    UsersModel.objects.all().delete()
```

For some reason, calling UsersModel.objects.all() raises the error

```
DatabaseError: column "cs169proj1_usersmodel.user" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or 
be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "cs169proj1_usersmodel"."user", "cs169proj1_usersmode...
```

From Googling, I've found that this particular error in SQL only comes up on Postgresql (which I'm using). Anyone know how to get around/fix this?

Comment: Do you have a custom manager on this model?

Comment: I don't think it is the cause of the error but you should be careful when using something else than the id as primary_key. It may cause troubles with the admin site : see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2011629/117092

Comment: Fixed it! I deleted and recreated the database, then ran manage.py syncdb. Don't know what it was, but it's gone now.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like the column name **`count`** is misinterpreted as [aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html).

Best solution: Never use [**reserved words**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as identifiers.

Comment: This persisted after deleting the count column. I chose count as the name because this is for a class project, and I was just following the spec.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita: Of course it wouldn't reference the field `count` if that was mistakenly taken to be an aggregate function.

Comment: Good point... Can postgresql get confused even if django quotes all SELECT args? "table"."count".

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita: No, PostgreSQL couldn't be confused. The column name would be `count` while the aggregate function would be `count(something)`. The confusion would have to happen earlier in the food chain. And I am not convinced that's what actually happened, but my advice is good in any case.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! They have been insightful to me!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into simillar issue when upgrading from django 1.6 to 1.9.8 on production with postgresql.

In my case the issue was due to change in Django 1.9 requiring at least postgresql 9.1 as described [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26148).

Nice postgresql update instruction for redhat/centos [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98144/how-to-upgrade-postgresql-8-4-to-9-4).